# CAFFE: Run forward pass with fewer nodes in FC layer

Tags: neural-network, caffe

I am trying to perform an experiment in Caffe with a very simple single hidden layer NN. I am using the MNIST dataset trained with a single hidden layer (of 128 nodes). I have all the weights from the fully trained network already.

However, during the feed forward stage I would like to use only a smaller subset of these nodes i.e 32 or 64. So for example, I would like to calculate the activations of 64 nodes during the feed forward pass and save them. then during the next run, calculate the activations of the other 64 nodes and combine them with the activations of the first 64 so i get the activations of all 128 nodes. Thus calculating the activations of all 128 nodes but in two 'passes'.

Is there a way to achieve this in Caffe? Please excuse me as I am very new to Caffe ( just started using it this week! ).

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @malreddysid Hi, I am doing it as part of an experiment. I didnt want to go into details about that in my post so it wouldnt distract from what i was trying to do.

Comment: As far as I know, Caffe doesn't support this. But you could write your own layer to do this.

Comment: I would also recommend writing a custom layer in this case. You will only need to implement the selection process and then pass on both the feed forward activations as well as the backward errors. If you are using Python, have a look at these links for examples of custom layers: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/examples/pycaffe/layers, https://github.com/tnarihi/tnarihi-caffe-helper/tree/master/python/caffe_helper/layers, http://chrischoy.github.io/research/caffe-python-layer/

Comment: @DavidStutz Hi David, thank you! That seems like it would certainly work for me, however, would it be possible to build something like what I am trying to do, i.e calculate values for 32/128 nodes in the first 'pass', save them somewhere and then run the next 32 till i get the full 128 nodes? I am basically trying to do calculations for only 32 nodes at a time and gradually build up to the full accuracy of using all 128 nodes. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I guess it would be easier to let a standard layer calculate all 128 nodes, then use a custom layer to select some of the and pass them on to the next layer. This custom layer can also cache/save the values for the next pass. However, this might slow down training.

Comment: Hi @DavidStutz I am planning to train the network in the traditional way and reuse the weights for my experiment ( as what I am trying to do only pertains to the forward pass and doesnt affect training ). So for the forward pass, if i were to create another layer, how would I save the values between passes? It doesnt seem like Caffe has a mechanism by which i can save values from one run to be used in the subsequent run. Would I have to basically output intermediate values to a file and read them in for the next run?

Comment: This would be the naive way of doing it, but unfortunately I do not have a better idea right now. I am not sure how the custom Python layers are called in detail, so I am not sure whether you can keep the the saved values in RAM instead. For doing regular trianing, you can simply exclude the custom layer during training and use it for testing only.

Comment: @DavidStutz Thank you. Ill keep looking and in the meantime your suggestion seems to be the best approach.